# Dynamic loading and symbols sharing

Tags: module, shared-libraries, symbols, dynamic-loading

I'm trying to load a module library via `dl` in such way, that the module can access globals from the main application. How is that possible to do?

I get an error message from dlopen saying `library/name.so: undefined symbol: ...`. The only flag used is: `RTLD_NOW`.

The module itself is build with libtool with `-module -avoid-version`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is: use `-Wl,--export-dynamic` when linking the main binary, so all symbols are automatically exported to the loaded libraries.

Same question, just asked differently: [Receive "undefined symbol" error when loading library with dlopen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/480617/dlopen-issue)